# plot histogram of frequency of values occurring in a column based on list of values from another file

Tags: r

I appreciate any kind of help.
I want to calculate the frequency of values in a column based on a list of values in another file.

```
l1 <- data.frame(V1 = c("A1", "A2", "B-1", "C", "D", "E1")

l2 <- data.frame(
          V1 = c("m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5", "m6"), 
          V2 = c("A1", "A1", "E1", "C", "D", "E1")
      )
```

I want to plot a histogram for frequency of values in `V2` of `l2`. But-x axis values should be `l1`. For example A2 and B-1 are missing in `l2$V2`, but it should still show them as labels on x-axis. Can we do this in ggplot?

I tried `barplot(table(x$V2))`.

Plot histogram with l1 being x-axis labels. And the frequencies l2$V2 (ex: A1 - 2, the frequency should be = 2/6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily calculate the frequency of V2 (in l2) with the function `count()` from the library **dplyr**.

```
library(dplyr)
count(l2, V2)

#   V2        n
# 1 A1        2
# 2 C         1
# 3 D         1
# 4 E1        2
```

Then, transform `l1` to a dataframe, and merge it with the result of the count in order to keep all the levels in `l1`:

```
l1 <- c("A1", "A2", "B-1", "C", "D", "E1")
left_join(data.frame(V2 = l1), count(l2, V2), by = 'V2') 

#    V2  n
# 1  A1  2
# 2  A2 NA
# 3 B-1 NA
# 4   C  1
# 5   D  1
# 6  E1  2
```

Then you can divide by number of observations (6 in this case) to calculate the proportion, and you can build an histogram (with **ggplot2** for instance, or with `barplot()` if your prefer).

```
library(ggplot2)
left_join(data.frame(V2 = l1), count(l2, V2), by = 'V2') %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = V2, y = n)) + 
   geom_col()
```